# Wufoo form in front of an image on an HTML page?

Tags: html, css, image, z-index, wufoo

I have a typical Wufoo form and have added it to a site that I'm working on, built using plain old HTML and CSS. In the form, I have a date field that, when clicked on, opens a little calendar date picker. I also have an image beside the form, created using the `<img>` tags. However, when I click to open the date picker, it shows up behind the image.

I have tried putting the form in a div and setting the `z-index` property higher than that of the image, but the image still appears on top. I have also tried setting the image as the background image of a div, and changing its `z-index` property to something lower than that of the form, but it still overlaps in front of it.

If anyone has any solutions as to how I can put the image behind the form, they would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try setting the image as a background image of a div or something using css.

Comment: Have already tried setting the image as a background image of a div with a low z-index, but to no avail. Any other ideas?